# How to format $email array for mailchimp

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

So, I'm trying to send an email via the mailchimp api... the documentation regarding the MCAPI class and its methods seems fairly straight-forward, so far. I'm having a hard time figuring out what mailchimp is expecting for the email array.... I know it needs header info, to, from, body etc... but what is the format that it wants? Does anyone know off hand - or have a link to the proper docs? Much thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this would be better off on Mailchimp's support forum.

Comment: Are you trying to subscribe someone to the list, or send an email: what specific task are you doing?

Comment: @Femi - send an email :)

Comment: What specific method(s) are you using? I'm guessing SendEmail from the STS v1.0 API, but until that's clarified, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you can see a previous chunk of code (with its associated corrections) at [Send an email via MailChimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284988/send-an-email-via-mailchimp).

The specific chunk (I think) you want is this: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/how-to/transactional-campaigns.php. it goes through the thinking behind sending one-off emails using pseudo-transactional campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, you're supposed to work with email-campaigns. There is a pretty good example and explanation on their site: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/1.3/campaigncreate.func.php